# Is there a Win10 shortcut to return the mouse pointer to the last clicked location?

Tags: windows, mouseevent, autohotkey

I wondered if there's a way of returning the mouse pointer to its last clicked location in Win10?

The desired behaviour would be:

User clicks left key on mouse. This can be anywhere in the browser window, it doesn't have to be a UI element.
User uses moves mouse to another location.
User presses shortcut keys.
Mouse is returned to its last clicked location.

I've seen AHK scripts that return the mouse pointer to a specific location on the screen, but nothing that records a clicked location and then returns the mouse pointer, using a shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by mapping LButton (Left Mouse Button) to a hotkey with the Wildcard (*) and Tilde (~) [modifiers](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) so that the hotkey will activate even if other keys are being held down, and the hotkey will not suppress the Mouse button's normal functions respectively. This hotkey will capture the current position of the mouse using the [MouseGetPos](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm) command and save the x and y coordinates into variables (in this case, `xpos` and `ypos` respectively).

Next, we can create another Hotkey (Control+q in this example) to move the mouse using the [MouseMove](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm) command back to the position saved in the variables. To map this to a hotkey of your choice, check out the page on [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro) in the docs.

---

Resulting Code:

```
*~LButton::MouseGetPos, xPos, yPos
^q::MouseMove, xPos, yPos
```

Comment: Remember to set coordmode.

Comment: @Incertus, if this solution solves your problem, could you please mark it as the accepted answer so that others know this problem is solved?